# Help to review ISA Server 2006 web publish settings

Tags: isa-server, web

I have a internal site named myinternalsite, and I want to publish all information in the internal site to my external internet domain http://www.myexternalsite.com and under order path, i.e. when accessing http://www.myexternalsite.com/order, the homepage of myinternalsite will be displayed.

Here are my screen snapshots for key steps in ISA Server 2006 Management Console, please help to review whether my settings are correct?

http://i39.tinypic.com/fmnk9e.jpg

http://i42.tinypic.com/35mhdlx.jpg

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2):

Those seem ok, but it does depend on a number of other settings.

What problems are you getting when you follow this through to conclusion?

Comment: Thanks, Bravax! I have not tested it, and I just want to make sure the major settings that I map an internal server to a path of an external domain is correct. Then a further question, my ISA server's host/DNS name needs to be www.myexternalsite.com?

Comment: For the way you're setting it up, you would need to have the DNS resolve to your server, but you could have multiple names pointing at one ISA Server. (We're on 4 currently...)

Comment: "DNS resolve to your" -- you mean resolve www.myexternalsite.com to the machine installed with ISA server?

Comment: www.myexternalsite.com should resolve the the public IP address of your ISA Server (if it's directly connected to the router/internet) - myinternalsite should resolve to your internal server (I suppose your Windows Domain Server should have that host name pointing to your internal web server).

Comment: Thanks splattne, I have posted my further confusions about host header below (comments section in reply to your answer), could you help to answer please? :-) Your comment above is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Looks okay. But of course "internalsite" should be the host header of your internal site and ISA Server should be able to resolve that DNS name. If you're using the default web on the internal server, which normally accepts all headers, you could also use the server's name.

Here is another link (Forefront TMG (ISA Server) Product Team Blog): [Another Look at Web Publishing. Part I: Host Headers without SSL](http://blogs.technet.com/isablog/archive/2008/06/19/another-look-at-web-publishing-part-i-host-headers-without-ssl.aspx)

*Hope this helps.*

Comment: Thanks, splattne! 1. "ISA Server should be able to resolve that DNS name" -- means resolve www.myexternalsite.com to the machine installed with ISA server? 2. Yes, I am using default web of IIS on internal server, but I am confused about why you mentioned it is important -- "internalsite should be the host header of your internal site"? I think internal site just handles all requests to it and response appropriately, why header matters (you mean request header from external client or response header of internal server to external client request)?

Comment: ad 2.: okay, if it's your default site, it will handle all host headers (if not explictly set in other webs).

Comment: Example for making clear what I mean by "host headers". When you create a new site, you can configure IIS to have multiple web sites listening to port 80 of the same IP address, but distinguish the site by its domain name (= host header).

Comment: Thanks @splattne, I read your recommended document from begin to the end. I found there are two options for how to deal with request host headers (do you mean request host header? Or some other host header? Can you confirm please?), one is keep host header to be the same as original client request (i.e. value is ISA Server's host name), the other option is to change the host value to be the same as the internal server name. I think you advice is to let ISA Server to change the host value to be the internal server name. Why should we trigger this change? Benefits?

Comment: Thanks @splattne, I understand on the same machine, we can create multiple sites to share the same port but different domain name. But why you specially mentioned default site, any exceptions?